# How to check parameter existance in myBatis mapper XML?

Tags: sql, spring, mybatis, dynamic-sql, mybatis-dynamic-sql

I simplifed my problem as following code.

Mapper Interface looks like:

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {
 public Integer countTable(@Param("tValue1") Integer tValue1);
 public Integer maxTable(@Param("tValue2") Integer tValue2);
}
```

Mapper Xml looks like:

```
<sql id="sql_where">
   <where>
      <if test="tValue1 != null">tValue1 = #{tValue1}</if>
      <if test="tValue2 != null">AND tValue2 = #{tValue2}</if>
   <where>
</sql>

<select id="countTable" resultType="Integer">
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
  <include refId="sql_where"/>
</select>

<select id="maxTable" resultType="Integer">
  SELECT MAX(*) FROM TestTable
  <include refId="sql_where"/>
</select>
```

when countTable or maxTable method is called, BindingException occurs.
Due to one of parameter is not found.

How can I check the parameter exists in XML?
I could've insert all params to method, but I don't want programmers to be confused (they're not going to be used)

Comment: If you use `@Param`, you may be able to check the existence with `<if test="_parameter.containsKey('tValue1')">`.

Comment: Any updates on the solution for this problem?